# SyncFolderHierarchy is not working with Exchange server 2007

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I send following soap request to exchange server 2007 using objective-c.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <SyncFolderHierarchy  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </FolderShape>
    </SyncFolderHierarchy>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

On reply i got "The request is invalid." response from the server 
This request work fine with exchange server 2010 and 2013.
but not working with exchange server 2007.

---

- SyncFolderHierarchy is supported by exchange server 2007 
reference :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa564829%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

---

My question is that 
[1] Is there any settings i have to make in exchange server for SyncFolderHierarchy operation ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Objective-C or iPhone? The question seems to be completely about Exchange server requests.

Comment: i create application in iphone that's why i added that tags,

Comment: It doesn't sound like your problem has anything to do with iPhones, though.

Comment: It is because when i use EWS managed API in c# it does not give any error

Comment: Then post some code, or anything at all that's related to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm querying Exchange 2010, but I had to include a header:

```
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\">"
                             @"<soap:Header>"
                             @"<t:RequestServerVersion Version =\"Exchange2010_SP2\"/>"
                             @"</soap:Header>"
                             @"<soap:Body>"
                             @"<m:GetRooms>"
                             @"<m:RoomList>"
                             @"<t:EmailAddress>%@</t:EmailAddress>"
                             @"</m:RoomList>"
                             @"</m:GetRooms>"
                             @"</soap:Body>"
                             @"</soap:Envelope>"
                             @"", roomlist];
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no Exchange 2007 environments on which to test.